# Is Grassmann-Plucker relation implied by 3-term Grassmann-Plucker relation?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

It's a problem from book "Oriented Matroid", problem 3.16. More exactly:
For $n$ elements $i_1,\dots,i_n$ and an anti-symmetric function $\det$ on${\{i_1,\dots,i_n\}}^r$. we have:

$\det(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r)*\det(y_1,y_2,x_3,\dots,x_r)-\det(x_1,y_1,\dots,x_r)*\det(x_2,y_2,x_3,\dots,x_r)+\det(x_1,y_2,\dots,x_r)*\det(y_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_r)=0$

do we necessarily have:

$\det(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r)*\det(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_r)=\sum_{i=1}^r\det(y_i,x_2,\dots,x_r)*\det(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_{i-1},x_i,y_{i+1},\dots,y_r)$

($x_1,\dots,x_r,y_1,\dots.y_r\in\{i_1,\dots,i_n\}$)?

I'm able to have the proof when $\det(x_i,\dots,x_r)$ is non-zero when $x_i,\dots,x_r$ are all different,the sketch was like:

for convenience we suppose $\det(i_i,\dots,i_r)=1$. So
$\det(y_1,y_2,y_3,x_4,\dots,x_r)*\det(x_1,x_2,y_3,x_4,\dots,x_r)=\det(x_1,y_1,y_3,x_4,\dots,x_r)*\det(x_2,y_2,y_3,x_4,\dots,x_r)-\det(x_1,y_2,y_3,x_4,\dots,x_r)*\det(y_1,x_2,y_3,x_4,\dots,x_r)=0$ and can be further expanded. This gives the Plucker relation of $x_4=y_4,\dots,x_r=y_r$ case. continue this procedure we can prove the Plucker relation of most general case.

But I'm nor sure for the remaining part. Can any body give me some idea on how to deal with this?