# Answered question. Ball on shadow

Tags: geometry

asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf

Comment: I've edited the tags; your question has nothing to do with any of tags you've had attached at first.

Comment: Good question, but it depends on the rotations you make. In the example of the cylinder, you can make one rotation of 180$^o$ (swapping flat ends) and there will be no difference in the shadow. You can also make any rotation about the axis through the centre of the flat ends without any change in the shadow. You therefore need to be more specific about the kinds of rotations you will allow.

Comment: $B$ could be a ball with a tiny bump on top, and if you make small rotations the bump will have no effect on the shadow cast by $B$.

Comment: Consider the how the [Steinmetz](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html) [solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid) is constructed, you can have as many arbitrary orientations as you want.

Comment: @littleO I think the OP has to restraint his quest to **convex** shapes.

Comment: @JeanMarie I agree the question is more interesting if $B$ is restricted to be convex.

Comment: A cilinder works for all your cases. But what if $B$ is compact and convex and _every_ rotation has a perfectly round shadow? Does $B$ then have to be a sphere?

Comment: @ Magdiragdag The answer is yes : see https://mathoverflow.net/q/39127

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your former title into a more informative one (it is important to drain more people to look at your question). I wish you don't object...

Comment: Thank you for your changes. I am confused is the answer yes or no?

Comment: @JeanMarie Could you further explain why it is yes and try to talk with other people here and see which is the correct response?

Comment: Sorry I was sleeping (8:00 AM Central European Time). The answer to the title is "no" if we take the good orientations as examplified by my counterexample. But, if we modify the title into "... in **any** three (mutually) orthogonal directions, the answer would be "yes".

Comment: @JeanMarie What about the answers to "Must B be a perfectly round ball? What if you are able to rotate B twice, getting now two new orientations, and all three shadows that you see are perfectly round and of the same diameter. Must B be a ball?"

Comment: @GamingCobra: Do not vandalize your own question (or anyone else's!) by deleting its contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove a little cap to a sphere : you will be able to find three  orthogonal directions in which projections will be perfect disks.

Comment: here is a question from ten years ago, one answer is by Thurston

Comment: @Will Jagy Hi, Will. I would appreciate a reference.

Comment: there is a final answer there from about 2016 by Anton Petrunin, he gives some references in Russian and translation refs. I'm guessing Joseph O'Rourke might have some favorite references  https://math.stackexchange.com/users/237/joseph-orourke  as he gets computers to draw surfaces; his faculty page  http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/

Comment: @Will Jagy Thanks for the references. On my side, I can indicate you a good book, recently published : "Handbook of Geometric constraint systems principles" (what a title) Meera Sitharam, Audrey St. John, Jessica Sidman, CRC Press, 2019. For example, it is the first book where I see mentionned and used the Grassman-Pluecker relationships, that I used for the first time in a recent question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493048) ; by the way, I am almost certain that there are different ways to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the title. It appears the campus libraries here have this Handbook just as an electronic resource, cannot just check it out: http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b24726678~S1

Comment: Is this the only answer (to remove the little cap) Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Somebody has said no and linked this: https://mathoverflow.net/q/39127 what do you think

Comment: @WillJagy So what is the correct answer?