# What is the maximum volume of a pyramid inscribed with a sphere that has the radius 1. Explanations also please.

Tags: geometry

What is the maximum volume of a pyramid inscribed with a sphere that has the radius 1? Explanations also please.

Comment: the base is ? a square, rectangle, polygon.. ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no maximum volume because every inscribed [pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry)) will be strictly contained in another inscribed pyramid, which may, for instance, be constructed by "doubling the vertices" of its basis.

*Added:* In fact let $\mathcal B$ be the basis and $V$ be the vertex of any pyramid. The plane where $\mathcal B$ lies intersects the sphere in some ellypse where $\mathcal B$ is an inscribed $n$-gon. By selecting two consecutive vertices $P$, $Q$ of $\mathcal B$, choosing a point $P'$ on the arc that joins $P$ with $Q$ and which lies in the half-space that doesn't contain $\mathcal B$, and finally considering the $(n+1)$-gon $\mathcal B'$  the vertices of which are $P'$ and the vertices of $\mathcal B$, we obtain an inscribed polygon with area strictly larger than $\mathcal B$. Now, the pyramid with basis $\mathcal B'$ and vertex $V$ has strictly larger volume than the one originally considered.

Comment: do not catch your reasoning

Comment: This doesn't address the question : the OP's concern is either a square based pyramid or a triangle-based one (= simplex).

Comment: @JeanMarie According to whom?

Comment: Let $P$ be a pyramid with basis some $n$-gon $Q$ and vertex $V$. Consider the plane passing through the basis. In that plane, the basis is some cyclic $n$-gon in the intersected circle. Construct inscribed $(2n)$-gon that has vertices the veritces of $Q$ ans some others (say, the ones on the bisectors ot the central angles of $Q$). This new polygon $Q'$ is the basis of a new incribed pyramid with vertex $V$, which is obviously larger.

Comment: Write your last comment into the answer and state at the beginning that you assume an arbitrary polygon as the base. This is a valid interpretation of pyramid but as it does not lead to an interesting answer presumably not what OP meant.

Comment: The OP just wrote that he/she has a square pyramid in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Given a base, the max volume will be when the pyramid is *straight*: apex over the centroid.
Assuming the base is a square, then two opposite vertices of it will lay on a great circle together with the apex.
The volume is proportional to the square of the diagonal of the base multiplied by the apex height.

Thus it will be maximum same as for any other pyramid with a cyclic polygon for base and in the limit same as for a circular cone.

If the diagonal is $d=2 \sin \alpha$ the apex height is $h=1+ \cos \alpha$ and I suppose you know how to maximize $d^2 h$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: probably I did not explain clearly that the points that lay on the great circle are two diagonally opposite vertices of the base (assuming it is square) and the apex.

Comment: @G Cab As I know you like geometry, here is a question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493608 to which I have given an intricate  answer using non classical properties of determinants (Pluecker-Riemann relationships) ;  I just discovered this evening that it is a version of "Tomihisa identity" with a nice geometric connection with Pappus theorem.

Answer (score 1):

(See figure) Let us denote by $S$ the apex of the pyramid, by $A_1A_2A_3A_4$ its base, by $I$ the center of this base, and by $O$ the center of the sphere.

[image]

For symmetry reasons, $O$ must belong to altitude $SI$.

Let $h:=OI$ (distance from the center of the sphere to the base square)

Let us recall that the volume of a pyramid is

$$V(h)=\tfrac13 B \times H\tag{1}$$

(where $B$ is its base area and $H$ its height, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(geometry))).

We are going to express $B$ and $H$ as functions of parameter $h$.

Triangle $OIA_k$ (for any $k$), being a right triangle with right angle in $I$, Pythagoras theorem gives :

$$OA_k^2=OI^2+IA_k^2 \ \ \iff \ \ 1 = h^2+IA_k^2$$

As a consequence : $IA_k=\sqrt{1-h^2}$.

Therefore the diagonal of the square is $2 IA_k=2\sqrt{1-h^2}$. But the diagonal of a square is $\sqrt{2}$ times its sidelength. As a consequence, the side length of the square base is $A_1A_2=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-h^2}$, giving this expression for the base area :

$$B=(A_1A_2)^2=2(1-h^2)\tag{2}.$$

Besides, the height can be written $H=OS+OI=1+h$.

Therefore, using (1), it remains to

> Maximize $V(h)=\tfrac23 (1-h^2) (1+h)$

This maximum (see figure below ; for the proof, see Remark 1 below) is achieved for

> $h_0=\tfrac13$ and its value is $V(h_0)=\dfrac{64}{81}=0.790123456790....  \ \ \ \ (3)$

[image]

*Graphical representation of function $v=V(h)$. Please note that we have also considered negative values of $h$ : the maximum could have occurred with $O$ below the base...*

**Remarks :**

1) In order to find the abscissa of the maximum (or more exactly the extrema) consider $V'(h)=0$, i.e., $(1+h)(1-3h)=0$. The root of interest is $h=\tfrac13$. The other (spurious root) can be interpreted on the figure as giving volume... $0$ to the pyramid.

2) the fact that $h_0=\tfrac13$ means that $O$ is such that $OS/OI=3$.

3) (3) gives a funny decimal expansion with increasing digits ..01234567... I have no clear explanation for that...

Comment: Just found a similar solution [there](https://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/differential-calculus/66-67-maxima-and-minima-pyramid-inscribed-in-a-sphere-and-indian-tepe).

Answer (score 1):

If "inscribed with a sphere" means that all faces of the pyramid touch the sphere then the volume of the pyramid can be arbitrarily large. Take as base the square $[-(1+\epsilon),1+\epsilon]^2$ and put the sphere onto the center of the square.

Comment: I believe the OP meant inscribed "into" a sphere...

Answer (score 0):

Hint assuming a square base.

One can set this up in coordinates with only one unknown. Assume the sphere has center $(0,0,0)$. Set the bottom square parallel to the $xy$-plane with two corners at $(\pm \cos(\alpha), 0, -\sin(\alpha))$ and the other two at $(0, \pm \cos(\alpha), -\sin(\alpha))$, the top is at $(0,0,1)$, $\alpha$ varies from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. You can now compute the volume as a function of $\alpha$ and compute the local maximum by standard calculus.